# Как отправлять видео в сообщении телеграм бота?

Tags: python, telebot

Здарвуствуйте! Бот оправляет новым юзерам в чате привет, нужно, чтобы он ещё и отправлял маленькое видео.
В сообщении форварднутом. Как это сделать?
Вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    bot.reply_to(message ,text = 'Привет, солнышко')
```

библиотека pytelegrambotapi

Answer (score 3):

у метода `send_video` имеется аргумент `reply_to_message_id`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_member(message):
    img = open('files/file.mp4', 'rb')
    bot.send_video(message.chat.id, img, None, 'Caption', message.message_id)
    img.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]